# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

**When I migrate below model its occure error i dont understand why occure error any solve it.**

File "C:\Users\Aqib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py", line 107, in parse_datetime
match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**

In my models:.

```
models.py

from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .managers import LikeManager


class Like(models.Model):
    """
    """

    user = models.ForeignKey(getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL', 'auth.User'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    target_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    target_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    target = GenericForeignKey('target_content_type', 'target_object_id')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    objects = LikeManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp"]
        get_latest_by = "timestamp"
        unique_together = ("user", "target_content_type", "target_object_id")
        verbose_name = _("like")
        verbose_name_plural = _("likes")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{} liked {}".format(self.user, self.target)
```

In my manager.py file

```
manager.py
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models
from django.apps import apps


def _get_content_type_and_obj(obj, model=None):
    if isinstance(model, str):
        model = apps.get_model(*model.split("."))

    if isinstance(obj, (int, int)):
        obj = model.objects.get(pk=obj)

    return ContentType.objects.get_for_model(type(obj)), obj


class LikeManager(models.Manager):
    """
    A Manager for Like objects
    """
    from django import VERSION
    if VERSION > (1,8):
        def get_query_set(self):
            return self.get_queryset()

    def for_user(self, user, model=None):
        """
        Returns a Like objects queryset for a given user.

        If a model params is provided, it returns only the
        liked objects of that model class

        Usage:

            Like.objects.for_user(user)
            Like.objects.for_user(user, model=Song)
            Like.objects.for_user(user, model="music.song")
        """

        qs = self.get_query_set().filter(user=user)

        if model:
            if isinstance(model, str):
                model = apps.get_model(*model.split("."))

            content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model)
            qs = qs.filter(target_content_type=content_type)

        return qs.order_by("-timestamp")

    def for_model(self, model):
        """
        Returns a Like objects queryset for a given model.
        `model` may be a django model class or an string representing
        a model in module-notation, ie: "auth.User"

        Usage:

            Like.objects.for_model(Song)
            Like.objects.for_model("music.Song")
        """

        # if model is an app_label.model string make it a Model class
        if isinstance(model, str):
            model = apps.get_model(*model.split("."))

        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model)

        qs = self.get_query_set().filter(
            target_content_type=content_type
        )

        return qs.order_by("-timestamp")

    def for_object(self, obj, model=None):
        """
        Returns a Like objects queryset for a given object

        Usage:
            Like.objects.for_object(1, "music.Song")
            Like.objects.for_object(1, Song)

        or given a music app with a Song model:

            song = Song.objects.get(pk=1)
            Like.objects.for_object(song)
        """

        content_type, obj = _get_content_type_and_obj(obj, model)

        qs = self.get_query_set().filter(
            target_content_type=content_type,
            target_object_id=obj.pk
        )

        return qs.order_by("-timestamp")

    def get_like(self, user, obj, model=None):
        """
        Returns a Like instance if the `user` has liked
        the given object `obj`. Otherwise returns None

        Usage:
            Like.objects.get_like(user, 1, "music.Song")
            Like.objects.get_like(user, 1, Song)

        or given a music app with a Song model:

            song = Song.objects.get(pk=1)
            Like.objects.get_like(user, song)
        """

        content_type, obj = _get_content_type_and_obj(obj, model)

        try:
            return self.get_query_set().get(
                user=user,
                target_content_type=content_type,
                target_object_id=obj.id
            )
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def create(self, user, obj, model=None):
        """
        Creates and returns a new Like obj for the given user and obj
        """

        content_type, content_object = _get_content_type_and_obj(obj, model)
        like = super(LikeManager, self).create(
            user=user,
            target_content_type=content_type,
            target_object_id=content_object.pk,
            target=content_object
        )

        return like
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are returning something other than a string. check out this usage of datetime [here](https://medium.com/@stackpython/django-errors-solving-63e497cd560a)

Answer (score 0):

Django's "auto_now_add=True" directive can sometimes cause problems (in your case, this could possibly be due to the complex manager and meta). This is quite complex to solve properly, but what might help may be to remove the "auto_add_now" directive, you can write a save procedure to set the timestamp (do the same thing) like so:

```
class Like(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.timestamp == None:
             self.timestamp = timezone.now()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```